# Can't Manage to install the xlsx package on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: java, r, xlsx

I am trying to install the xlsx R package on a 64 bit Windows 10.

I have tried to run

```
install.packages('xlsx')
```

and got the errors

[image]

Then I tried to manually install the dependencies with

```
install.packages('xlsxjars')
```

but got

[image]

Then I tried to install rJava but got

[image]

I have read many posts, I tried to set and unset the java home path variable, I have checked that I have the latest versions of R and Java (both for 64bit).

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="")
    Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")
library(rJava)
```

then installed everything with the INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch" e.g

```
install.packages("xlsxjars", INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

this seemed to solve the problem